# POISSON Distribution help

Tags: statistics

I already know the answer to this question. This was on a quiz which I got wrong. I can't figure out how to do this. The correct answer is "0.1396" but I can't work it out. If someone can explain how to do this it will be highly appreciated.

"Cars are arriving at a toll booth at a rate of four per minute. What is the probability that exactly eight cars will arrive in the next two minutes?"

Comment: what do you know property do you know about Poisson distributions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cars arrive at a rate of 4 every minutes than an average of 8 arrives every two minutes.

For the formula I use,

$
p(y) = \displaystyle \frac{\lambda^y}{y!}e^{-\lambda}
$

where $\lambda$ is the average amount over the interval.

So if want the probability of eight cars passing then:

$
p(8) = \displaystyle \frac{8^8}{8!} e^{-8} = .1396
$

Answer (score 0):

If the rate is 4 per minute, it is also 8 per two minutes. Therefore, you are looking at $P(X=8)$, where $X$ is a Poisson random variable with mean 8.